# Specified resource is not supported for MSA requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create a subscription for 'events' with endpoint v1.0 using personal account and I get "Specified resource is not supported for MSA requests" error. However the documentation says it's supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a documentation issue as subscription creation for 'events' is only available via the beta endpoint.